# Подключение к удаленному URL-адресу, для которого требуется аутентификация с использованием Java?

Tags: java

Хочу получить данные с http запросом, но сайт защищен логином и паролем.
Выдает ошибку 401.

Вот Код:

```
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String query = "";
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            try {
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(query).openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.setUseCaches(false);
                connection.setConnectTimeout(250);
                connection.setConnectTimeout(250);
                connection.connect();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                if (HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK == connection.getResponseCode()) {
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                    String line;
                    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                        sb.append("\n");
                    }
                    System.out.println(sb.toString());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("fail :" + connection.getResponseCode());
                }
            } catch (Throwable cause) {
                cause.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: У Вас есть логин и пароль? Если да, то Вам нужно знать какой способ авторизации на данном сайте. Или авторизация на определенном URL с сохранением сессии или Basic авторизация при обращении к любому ресурсу сайта. Если Basic , то необходимо просто добавить заголовок: Authorization: Basic [логин:пароль] - в кодировке Base64.

Comment: да, Пароль и логин знаю. Мне нужно в заголовках указать логин и пароль

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите здесь [HttpURLConnection Authenticator](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/URL_Connection_Address/Java_HttpURLConnection_with_Authenticator.htm) и здесь [Connecting to remote URL which requires authentication using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496651/connecting-to-remote-url-which-requires-authentication-using-java).